# Invoke WSO2 IS Web service using SAML2 token authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently our apps integrate (service provider) with WSO2 IS v5.1.0 with multitenancy. We are using SAML2 Web SSO Authentication. There is an requirement to do profile update, change password, manage user from service provider.

I found 1 sample apps that use SAML2 token for authentication
https://github.com/firzhan/saml2.sso.demo

The problem is: 
I need to specify ServiceProviderID in authenticators.xml (step no 3 on the link above).

Is there any way disabled this checking?